# Unable to identify which MAC address output of arp command or ip command is correct

Tags: linux, networking

I am using VMWare VCenter vm machine running RHEL 7.4.

When I issue **arp**, I get the below output:

```
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
xx.xx.xxx.xx             ether   00:50:56:b4:1f:18   C                     ens192
```

and when I issue **ip a s**, then the output is as follows:

```
ens192: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:50:56:b4:c1:76 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Now, I am unable to make sure which MAC address from the above output is correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `arp` command shows you the cache of learned MAC addresses of devices your server has talked with in the last couple of minutes, in that case devices that were seen by interface `ens192`.

On the other hand the `ip` command will show you the MAC address(es) of your interfaces.

So at the end of day, both are correct.

Evidently, for all purposes the MAC address of that interface is the one got via the `ip` command.

If using VMWare center, you will be also able to double confirm that in the graphical management interface.

BTW, be sure to use the (open)vm-tools and the vmxnet paravirtualized interfaces, they tax less the hypervisor and offer you one or two order of magnitude of better bandwidth performance. (please open a different question for that)

Comment: The `cat /sys/class/net/$INTERFACE/address` will give the right MAC address.

Comment: @GAD3R   Indeed, there are several ways of getting that; I was answering directly to the question, and whenever possible it is better to stick with the cmdline simplest tools for newbies.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro : thank you very much for the confirmation

Comment: Thank you @GAD3R : great! I learned a new other way to find MAC